# Using Netty application code with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, netty, iot, spring-webflux

I want to create a server for IoT (ODB GPS trackers for cars) that will send its status to server in real time and show it to client via a web applications.

The devices will connect to server using TCP, and then there will be client/web connecting to server via Websocket.

Spring Webflux is used for the client side. But I do not find a tutorial of Spring Boot TCP Server. And I read that netty is good for that (found an example using netty). So, because webflux is using netty underneath, can I use netty application code with spring boot?? Or is there a way using spring boot for tcp socket programming??

Comment: Consider RSocket protocol with Spring Boot? It supports TCP and Websocket protocol. Check [Spring RSocket Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#rsocket-spring), and [my RSocket sample](https://github.com/hantsy/rsocket-sample/tree/master/tcp).

Comment: @Hantsy Isn't RSocket a custom protocol? If so,  I could not use it for my IoT devices.

Comment: It is a new message protocol, see https://github.com/rsocket, includingng multi lang implementations, I think it is a good choice for IoT messaging.